# Accidentally installed Ubuntu Desktop program on Server - now things are playing up

Tags: server, gtk

I accidentally installed a program on Ubuntu Server which was actually for Ubuntu Desktop (Grsync). Now, other programs that worked fine are coming up with this error when run:

```
(Duplicati.GUI.TrayIcon:26310): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:05:28.218: cannot open display:
```

The program in question here is Duplicati, which runs a GUI through port 8200. Anyway I can fix my error?

Answer (score 0):

Set the DISPLAY manually, like so:

```
export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:10.0"
```

Add that line to the file ~/.bashrc and then X11 programs should be fine